# Static Files in Class Library; How to Copy to Website Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

In my Visual Studio Solution, I have a Website project, as well as a Web project (the latter a Class Library containing things like web-specific logic, HTTP handlers, etc.)

I would like to include shared static assets in the Web project like JavaScript and HTML template files. These files will be referenced and used in the Website but may be used in one or more other projects in the future, so I would like to keep them in a common project. Ideally they'll end up somewhere like /js or /templates in the Website. I'd prefer them not going in the /bin directory if possible, but I could be convinced that it's fine.

That said, what would be the most appropriate way to keep them in the Web project, but have them deployed with the Website at build/run and deployment time, whether debugging from Visual Studio or building with Jenkins/MSBuild? The options I see are "Copy to Output Directory" or some sort of embedded build action (not ideal, as I would like to copy the files into the output directory in their native format.)

Comment: Assets of that kind do not belong in a class library project (unless you'll be turning them into embedded resources or something). The output of a class library project is meant to be a .dll file and that's pretty much all. What's wrong with keeping these assets in your web application project?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Fair point, and I don't disagree, but do you know of any fun and exciting ways to consolidate static assets into a shared project of some sort? I defaulted to Class Library because I already have a Web-centric shared class library and I thought it would be a fitting place.

Comment: Not really. The best I can think of is a web application project with no code in it Just don't delete any .dll out of the bin folder after a build, and just deploy the rest.

Comment: The more I think of it, maybe it doesn't make sense. :) I remember hearing a while back that you could keep static assets like JS, CSS in a class library, but upon further reading I see now that it was referring to *embedded* assets. I've just had it in my head that keeping them in their own assembly would help with versioning, sharing, and possibly with deployment to a degree. I think for now I'm going to keep them in the Website app and that should be just fine. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: And I would use a web application project, and not a web site "project".

Comment: Yeah, of course. Sorry my nomenclature is all over the map today. I'm definitely using a Web Application Project. Just referring to it as a Website project to differentiate it from my Web class library (I have AppName.Web and AppName.Website projects.)